# Get the list of all fixture names defined in the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures, minitest

I have several fixtures files defined, and they are loaded by `fixtures :all` statement.
**How do I get an array of all fixture names that I have in the project?** Without going through test/fixtures folder searching for *.yml files.

P.S. An obvious solution would be defining a method like this:

```
def all_fixtures
    @all_fixtures ||= Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures")
                         .select { |filename| /.*\.yml/.match(filename) }
                         .map{ |filename| filename[0..-5].to_sym }
end
```

But I'm sure there's something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any other method outside of doing what you mentioned. However you can clean up that statement a bit.

Copying the logic directly from `ActiveRecord`'s `fixutres.rb`, you can do the following

```
def all_fixtures
  # Get the fixture path that's configured
  fixture_path = ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path
  # Get all YML files in all subdirectories
  fixture_set_names = Dir["#{fixture_path}/{**,*}/*.{yml}"]
  # Clip the name to get all the fixture names
  fixture_set_names.map! { |f| f[(fixture_path.to_s.size + 1)..-5] }
end
```